# Obtaining a MIN() value in a column in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I have the two following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE PC (
    model ..., 
    speed ..., 
    ram...,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE Laptop (
    model ..., 
    speed ..., 
    ram ..., 
    screen...,
    ...
);
```

And am trying to create a query that gives the model numbers of all laptops with a speed slower than that of any PC.

I came up with:

```
SELECT model
FROM Laptop, (SELECT MIN(speed) AS speed FROM PC)slowpcs
WHERE Laptop.speed < slowpcs.speed;
```

However even after double checking that I had added a laptop that meets this criterion and running the code, it's giving me an empty results list.

```
INSERT INTO Laptop
(model, speed, ram)
VALUES
(2006, 3.00, 2048),
(2007, 1.73, 1024),
(2009, 2.80, 512);

INSERT INTO PC
(model, speed, ram)
VALUES
(1070, 2.00, 1024,
(1071, 2.10, 512),
(1050, 1.90, 512);
```

Answer (score 3):

From your post:

```
INSERT INTO PC    
(model, speed, ram)
VALUES
(1070, 2.00, 1024, --- Missing closing parenthesis ')'
(1071, 2.10, 512),
(1050, 1.90, 512);
```

Once that was corrected, your query worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Does this get you your expected results?

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE #Laptop
(
    model INT,
    speed NUMERIC(9, 2),
    ram INT
);

INSERT INTO #Laptop ( model, speed, ram )
VALUES ( 2006, 3.00, 2048 ), ( 2007, 1.73, 1024 ), ( 2009, 2.80, 512 );

CREATE TABLE #PC
(
    model INT,
    speed NUMERIC(9, 2),
    ram INT
);

INSERT INTO #PC ( model, speed, ram )
VALUES ( 1070, 2.00, 1024 ), ( 1071, 2.10, 512 ), ( 1050, 1.90, 512 );


SELECT l.*
FROM   #Laptop AS l
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM #PC AS p WHERE p.speed > l.speed );

DROP TABLE #PC, #Laptop;
```

Answer (score 1):

> However even after double checking that I had added a laptop that
>   meets this criterion and running the code, it's giving me an empty
>   results list.

Your `INSERT INTO PC ...` statement has syntactic errors, and consequently, the `PC` table would be empty.

So the subquery

```
SELECT  min(speed) AS speed FROM PC;
```

is `NULL`. (try `SELECT  min(speed) IS NULL AS speed FROM PC;` to verify)

In turn, when you compare `Laptop.speed` to `NULL`, which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT model FROM Laptop
WHERE Laptop.speed < (SELECT MIN(speed) AS speed FROM PC);
```

you get an empty result table, no matter what the values of `Laptop.speed` in the laptop table.